# Get SNMP trap type using regex

Tags: regex

I need to get SNMP trap type from log file using regex and after that get this data in Elasticsearch

I've log file:
Thu Mar 28 11:16:53 2019 .1.3.6.1.4.1.15497.1.1.2.6 Major "test" test.test-test.test.com - updateFailure trap from test.test-6.test.com

I need to get "updateFailure" string. I've tried this regex [^-]*$  , but It returns me string after last "-" character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you get idea from this.

```
(?<=-)\s([^.]\w+)
```

https://rubular.com/r/Jw63oPUVgO4rfz

Result:

```
1.  updateFailure
```